# Does Node.js and SOCKET.IO framework works with jquery?

Tags: jquery, html, node.js, cordova

Hello in princible is there any conflict using node.js with jquery for fetching data from a phonegap app to the server

Comment: uhm.... no? they have differing purposes.

Comment: No. If you don't try to use jquery on the server side and node on the client side it will be ok.

Comment: Your question title asks the polar opposite question as what is in your question text. So, i guess the answer is both YES and NO.

Answer (score 0):

jQuery is a client-side Javascript framework, it runs entirely in the users' browser.

Socket.io is a websocket library for the server-side language PHP and Node.JS is a server-side language.

It does not matter what client-side language you use to communicate with a server-side language - all that the server side language needs is a format of communication it can properly decode (like JSON or XML sent via a POST request).